# Delete blue line in View android API 16

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

I need delete a blue line that appears in my application when I compile with API 20 or higher but doesn't appear when I compile in API < 20.

This image shows the blue line I need delete.

[image]
that is mi code view XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="280dp" >


    <net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1_popup"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title_picker"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title_picker"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title_picker"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/title_picker" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:background="@drawable/big_cancel"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/big_ok_line_green"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/title_picker"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
       </style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NowindowTitle">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

thanks for helpme

Comment: We'll need some code to help you.

Comment: the code is here thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your view appearance by setting background , etc if you want to remove that blue line . Because that is the default appearance for that platform (which I guess is started since Honeycomb).